# opencart | Print array of objects in twig file

Tags: twig, opencart

I'm using opencart. There I'm sending array of objects to twig file from controller.

**Controller**

```
$data['crackers'] = [];
    $results = $this->model_quickorder_order->getCrackers();

    $categories = [];
    foreach ($results as $row) {
        $categoryId = $row['category_id'];
        $categoryName = $row['category_name'];
        $productId = $row['product_id'];
        $productName = $row['name'];
        $specialPrice = $row['special'];
        $productPrice = $row['price'];
        $productImage = $row['product_image'];

        $product = [
            'product_id' => $productId,
            'product_name' => $productName,
            'special_price' => $specialPrice,
            'price' => $productPrice,
            'product_image' => $productImage,
        ];

        if (!isset($categories[$categoryId])) {
            $categories[$categoryId] = [
                'category_id' => $categoryId,
                'category_name' => $categoryName,
                'products' => [], // Initialize an array to hold products within this category
            ];
        }

        $categories[$categoryId]['products'][] = $product;
    }

    $categoriesArray = array_values($categories);
    $jsonCategories = json_encode($categoriesArray, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    $data['crackers'] = $jsonCategories;
    echo $data['crackers'];
```

**View file**

```
{{crackers}}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[ { "category_id": "67", "category_name": "Flower Pots", "products": [ { "product_id": "1", "product_name": "Flower Pots Small (10Pcs)", "special_price": "110.0000", "price": "220.0000", "product_image": "catalog\/flowerpotssmall.jpg" } ] }, { "category_id": "69", "category_name": "Chakkars", "products": [ { "product_id": "2", "product_name": "Zamin Chakkar Ashoka (10 pcs)", "special_price": "150.0000", "price": "300.0000", "product_image": "catalog\/Zamin_Chakkar_Asoka.jpg" } ] } ]
```

**Problem:**

When I use `foreach`, It does not work. when I print {crackers}, It prints as text as above output. Below code is not working.

```
{% for cracker in crackers %}
  <tr class='heading'>
    <td colspan="5"> {{ cracker.name }}</td>
  </tr>
 </td>
</tbody>
</tr>
 {% endfor %}
```

Comment: You are not passing an array but a (JSON) string

Comment: @DarkBee How I suppose to change the code. Could you add the answer.

Comment: Don't do this `$jsonCategories = json_encode($categoriesArray, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);`? Just pass `$categoriesarray`

Answer (score 0):

If you need to loop an array you should pass an array to the template and not a string. `$jsonCategories = json_encode($categoriesArray, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);` so this string was commented.

```
$categoriesArray = array_values($categories);
//  $jsonCategories = json_encode($categoriesArray, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
$data['crackers'] = $categoriesArray;
echo $data['crackers'];
```

and twig:

```
{% for cracker in crackers %}
            <tr class='heading'>
                <td colspan="5"> {{ cracker.category_name }}</td>
            </tr>
        </td>
        </tbody>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```